# Canvas - Draw only when hovering over new tile instead of whole canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

Let's say I have a canvas that is split into a 15x10 32-pixel checkboard. Thus, I have this:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var tileSize = 32;

var xCoord
var yCoord

var tilesX = 15; // tiles across
var tilesY = 10; // tiles up and down

var counted = 1; // for drawing purpose for checkerboard for visual guidance

var mouseSel = new Image()
mouseSel.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/vAA03NB.png' // mouse selection
mouseSel.width = 32
mouseSel.height = 32

    function isOdd(num) {
        return num % 2;
    }

    function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
        // super simple stuff here
        var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        return {
            x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
            y: evt.clientY - rect.top
        };
    }

drawCanvas(); // upon intilization... draw

function drawCanvas() {
    for (var y = 0; y <= 10; y++) {
        for (var x = 0; x <= 15; x++) {

            if (isOdd(counted)) {
                context.fillStyle = '#dedede'
                context.fillRect(x * 32, y * 32, 32, 32);
                // checkboard drawn complete.
            }

            counted++;
        } // end first foor loop

        counted++;
    } // end last for loop


    if (counted >= 176) counted = 1 // once all tiles (16x11) are drawn... reset counter for next instance

}


canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function (evt) {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // clear canvas so mouse isn't stuck
    drawCanvas(); // draw checkboard

    // get the actual x,y position of 15x10 32-pixel checkboard
    var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
    mousePos.xCoord = Math.floor(mousePos.x / tileSize)
    mousePos.yCoord = Math.floor(mousePos.y / tileSize)


    // draw the mouse selection
    context.drawImage(mouseSel, (mousePos.xCoord * 32), (mousePos.yCoord * 32), 32, 32) // draw mouse selection


    // debug
    var message = ' (' + mousePos.xCoord + ',' + mousePos.yCoord + ') | (' + mousePos.x + ',' + mousePos.y + ')';
    var textarea = document.getElementById('debug');
    textarea.scrollTop = textarea.scrollHeight;
    $('#debug').append(message + '\n');


}, false);
```

```css
canvas#canvas {
    background: #ABABAB;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" height="352" width="512" tabindex="0"></canvas>
<textarea name="" id="debug" cols="30" rows="35"></textarea>
```

**NOTE: ** Make sure to scroll down in that preview pane so you can see the debug textarea.

As you can see, the event of "drawing" fires EVERY single time it moves. That means every pixel.

I am trying to figure out how to make the drawing fire ONLY when a new x,y coord has changed. Because it'd be useless to redraw the mouse selection when it's only moved 5 pixels across and it's still going to be drawn at the same place.

**My suggestion**

Upon entering, have a temporary value and when that is passed, to redraw again?

Comment: You want to redraw when the user move from case (15x10 32-pixel) to another ?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a temporary value and update that if it was different from before. Then put the code in an `if` statement where either have changed.

```
var tempX, tempY;
var newX = 100;
var newY = 100;

tempX = mousePos.xCoord;
tempY = mousePos.yCoord;


if (newX !== tempX || newY !== tempY) {
    // code here
}

if (tempX !== newX) newX = mousePos.xCoord;
if (tempY !== newY) newY = mousePos.yCoord;
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/weka/bvnma354/8/